# What architecture to use for an extensive search

Tags: c#, sql-server, search, architecture

one of the things we're building right now is a search functionality to look for people.

When starting simple, we've used Linq to entities to search, like this: `Entities.People.Where(z=>z.Birthdate < birthdate).ToList()`

Then, when new searchcriteria were added, the linq statement grew and grew, and now we have to refactor it because nobody understands it anymore.

At this point, we must facilitate search for 8 related items, like 'did you work here', 'do you speak this language', 'from these 6 skills, which ones do you master' etc.

All these items are 1:N or N:N relations in SqlServer, and we are searching for multiple items AND we want to know 'how much match' you have.

For example: we look for people who speak french and or English and or German, and we want to get all people who have at least 1 match, and for those people, we want to know how many matches (ie 1 out of 3 or 2 out of 3) every person has.

At this point the question is: what is a smart thing to do (approx 10.000 people in the database).

Brainstorming has lead us to the following options:

1. Do the quickest search in the database (so you retrieve limited
   amount of records) and sort the rest in code
2. Keep on building with Linq
3. Perform the whole action in SqlServer

Any tips to get us started?

Answer (score 1):

If the Linq to Entities expression has grown to be too complex, that implies to me that your requirements are evolving fairly quickly.

Given the small total size of your database (10K records is pretty tiny), you may find it most efficient to write a SQL (or Linq to Entities) statement that returns all people who are potential matches, and apply the sorting in the business layer.

I say "efficient" because you are not losing much by not filtering some of the records on the database end (if the DB contained 10M records and you returned a substantial fraction, that would be less true), and because I sense from the way you write your question that your team may be more comfortable working in code.

Comment: I appreciate you answering my question even though it's marked as not constructive by others

Comment: StackOverflow is successful because it has a narrow, specific focus.  Your question is a good one, just not one that fits within that focus.  There is a companion site where your question is a probably a much better fit http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

As far as speed goes, as long as you are using a compiled query, your `select` performance is unlikely to be too different.  There was a [great article from Rico Mariani](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2007/06/22/dlinq-linq-to-sql-performance-part-1.aspx) where he detailed all the stuff they did to make LINQ faster with respect to SQL.  The punch line is, if you are using a compiled select statement (like you should be), then you're running pretty much as quickly as a stored procedure does - [93% as fast as raw SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2007/07/05/dlinq-linq-to-sql-performance-part-4.aspx), in fact.  If you're not using a compiled select, then you should read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76861/Linq-to-SQL-Performance-Considerations-Part-2) to give you an insight on how to make them.  A non-compiled select query is roughly half as fast as normal SQL, so there could be a nice gain there.

If speed isn't much of an issue and you are referring to the organizational task of keeping this complex-sounding database schema in line, then that's another thing altogther.  If that's the case then you probably want to start from the SQL level to at least make sure you have all the matches you want to have.  This is easy to test and SQL is optimized for that sort of searching.  You will also find it easier to confirm your work when you can get more or less immediate feedback from the server, instead of having to compile and run your program to test a scenario.

After you're sure you have everything you want and nothing you don't, you can handle the much smaller task of simply organizing it in C#, with whatever rules you have for prioritizing candidates.

EDIT: Whoops, I didn't see that Eric had an answer very similar to mine.  Oh well.

Comment: I appreciate you answering my question even though it's marked as not constructive by others